# when i passing datra frome app to firebase it stucks

Tags: android, firebase

Error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.zawalimarketsh, PID: 9060
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: 
Invalid Firebase Database path: sept. 09, 201911:25:22 AM. 
Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.Validation.validatePathString(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:45)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@19.0.0:102)
        at com.example.zawalimarketsh.AdminAddNewProductActivity.SaveProductInfoToDatabase(AdminAddNewProductActivity.java:219)
        at com.example.zawalimarketsh.AdminAddNewProductActivity.access$300(AdminAddNewProductActivity.java:33)
        at com.example.zawalimarketsh.AdminAddNewProductActivity$3$1.onComplete(AdminAddNewProductActivity.java:197)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:836)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6269)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Comment: Please provide code you have tried.

Comment: The error says that your path is `sept. 09, 201911:25:22 AM` but `.` is not allowed

Answer (score 0):

As the error states,

```
'.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
```

are not allowed inside paths and you are listening to the following path

```
sept. 09, 201911:25:22 AM
```

Either remove the . or change the path format to one which contains valid characters

Comment: where i have to change

Comment: remove the dot .